# How to add buttons and search bar into header at top of UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a search bar and some buttons in a view in my UITableViewController, but I don't know how to make that view the header? I've attached the referencing outlet to the UITableController. But currently the search bar and buttons scroll up and down with the tableview, but I want them to be the header so they stay fixed.

Here's a screen shot of what I currently have...

[image]

ok I ctrl/dragged from the view to my ViewController and created a IBOutlet, as you can see in this next image, and I added in the line to set it to be the header but it seems to give an error??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to move that view containing the search bar and buttons to being a subview of the view controller's view instead of inside the table view. Then apply your constraints so that it is pinned to the top and the table view is constrained to the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of elements you are displaying do not have more than one section, then you could implement the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: delegate method. Create the headerview containing the searchbar in storyboard and return the instance. It will be always on top of the list.

[Apple Documentaion](http://xcdoc://?url=developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/602958/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

Comment: "Create the headerview containing the searchbar in the storyoard and return the instance" - I thought that's what I've done? and how do you return the instance?